# How can I use the latest version of node with yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, nvm

I installed yarn and every time I run it, it gives a warning that "You are using Node "7.6.0" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || ^8.0.0""

If I check `node -v` I get `7.6.0` but if I run `nvm run node --version` I get `Running node v8.0.0 (npm v5.0.0)`

Is there a way to let yarn use the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvm run` only run the single command on the specified version. Use `nvm use` to switch to the specified version. `nvm --help` should cover that.